# i can't seem to understand what is causing the error

Tags: python

```
File "<ipython-input-193-4fdf3d1abd17>", line 1
    ConfusionMatrix(y_data, model.predict(y_data() , label= ["not_subscribed", "subscribed"])
                                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing an extra bracket, observe you have an EOF error. Try this

```
ConfusionMatrix(y_data, model.predict(y_data() , label= ["not_subscribed", "subscribed"]))
```

The python compiler is pretty friendly, as you can see where the error arrow is pointing to, most of time :)